# Installing a Library (dotless)

Tags: asp.net

Trying to install http://www.dotlesscss.org/ to my project and I'm a bit stuck on step 2

1. Include our reference to your web project

where do I put these files and how do I include this "reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the References in the solution explorer and select `Add Reference...`:

[image]

then in the Add Reference dialog select the `Browse` tab and point to the location of the `dotless.Core.dll` assembly which you extracted from the .zip file you downloaded in step 1.

Comment: what screenshot tool did you happen to use to snap that? I can never get context menus to stay open during my screenshots with snipping tool or gyazo.

Comment: @tester, the `Print Screen` key on my keyboard. Then pasted in Paint.